# Background Audio quiet when using AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I'm trying to reproduce the effects snapchat has with background audio like  music. When entering their app it stays at normal volume, even when recording. In my app it gets almost silent immediately upon opening the app.

I've tried using the .mixWithOthers, and .defaultToSpeaker options in AVAudioSession set category function. These make no difference.

```
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetooth, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .defaultToSpeaker])
            } else {
                let options: [AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions] = [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker]
                              let category = AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord
                let selector = NSSelectorFromString("setCategory:withOptions:error:")
                AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().perform(selector, with: category, with: options)
            }
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed to set background audio preference")

        }
```

Comment: "In my app it gets almost silent immediately upon opening the app.” Perhaps that is because you are configuring and activating the audio session immediately upon opening the app? If that’s the problem, don’t do that. Configure and activate the audio session only just before you really need to.

Comment: If my app opens up to the camera right away would I still not do it until I press the record button? I was under the impression I should do it right away once it gets to that recording view.

Comment: Well, let's experiment: try what I said (i.e. yes, don't do it until the record button is pressed) and see if the effect is closer to what you had in mind.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much :). I don't think I can pick you as top comment though sense you made a comment? Not sure how that works.

Comment: Well, it's great that it works - I'll turn my comment into an answer so we can close this out, if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my app it gets almost silent immediately upon opening the app.

Perhaps that is because you are configuring and activating the audio session immediately upon opening the app? If that’s the problem, don’t do that. Configure and activate the audio session only just before you really need to. For example, don't tweak the audio session until the user actually asks to start recording. It is *fine* to change the audio session category, as needed, throughout the lifetime of your app.